# Java File Explorer

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I am working on making a **PDF exclusive** Viewer that will be able to search your entire Hard Drive and be able to open **only PDF**. I am having an issue with being able to make the search box work with **JFileChooser** and making the search button look for what is typed into the search box.

```
package pdfView;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JButton ReFresh;

    public View() {
        //setting GUI
        super("PDF Viewer");
        setLookAndFeel();
        //set size box, try pack() method if not setSize(x, y)
        setSize(450, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        //set buttons
        JTextField Search = new JTextField ("Search", 29);
        JButton Search1 = new JButton("Search");
        //set actionListener
        ReFresh = new JButton("ReFresh");
        ReFresh.addActionListener(this);
        add(Search);
        add(Search1);
        add(ReFresh);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                }
        }} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.equals(ReFresh))
        {
            super.dispose(); 
            new View();

    }

}


    public static void main(String[] args){
        View pdf = new View();
    }
}
```

this is the file chooser, yes the code is most likely completely wrong. I have never worked with JFileChooser before.

```
package pdfView;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class FileChooser extends View {
    public static final int FILES_ONLY;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "PDF Files", "pdf");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        }
    }
```

[image: image of GUI for the PDF Viewer]

Comment: Your `FileChooser` can't compile because you're attempting to execute code outside of an executable context.  When did you want to show the file chooser?

Comment: (1) I realize the code is faulty big time. the first section of code works for the most part how I want it to. the second section of code is a trial and error piece (something to work off of). (2) I would like to launch the program and it look and behave just as the image depicts. search PDF, open PDF, Refresh and do it again.

Comment: But how does the file chooser fit into that picture?

Comment: I was lead to believe using JFileChooser would allow me to use the search box and look for and isolate PDF files. I may have been mistaken. I am Fairly new to Java.

Comment: Not really, the `JFileChooser` will present a dialog to the user to allow them to select a file or directory.  I think you might want something like [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) or [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)